# bad value error while using var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetID);

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the background of what I'm trying to make. I have 2 google forms and have separate spreadsheets for each.

Form 1: Will enter the following on spreadsheet 1

- Timestamp (default A column)
- Unique ID (B column)
- Requester's Name (C column)
- Requester's Email Address (D column)
- Request (E column)

So after the 1st form is submitted, it will generate an email to me, containing the 5 values. From there, there is a button I can click, where it will route to the second form where it is pre-filled with the 'Unique ID' and "Email Address" values from the 1st spreadsheet.

And these are the entries of the 2nd Form and Spreadsheet.

Form 2: Will enter the following on spreadsheet 2

- Timestamp (default A column)
- Unique ID (B column)
- Requester's Email Address (C column)
- Status of the request (D column) *radio button to update or close the request*
- Additional notes (E column) *notes to indicate what is the update on the request*

Now what I'm trying to accomplish, is I created the script on spreadsheet 2, to send an email to the "Requester's Email Address" where it will display the:

- Unique ID (same value from both spreadsheets 1 and 2)
- Request (an entry only found on spreadsheet 1)
- Status of the request (an entry only found on spreadsheet 2)
- Additional notes (an entry only found on spreadsheet 2)

That means, I would need to "Call" spreadsheet 1 so I can extract the "Request" data stored.

I got the value of the spreadsheet ID by using this function,

```
function getActiveSheetId(){
  var id  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  Logger.log(id.toString());
  return id;
}
```

I was trying to use this and but it always gives an error that the ID is "BAD Value" I don't know how it could be. Can someone help please. Thanks!

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID of the spreadsheet 1);`

Comment: openById() most likely doesn't take strings, remove the ' or "

Comment: @B.Go: Sorry if that caused confusion, and no, when I entered the ID I didn't put ' or ". Let me update that real quick. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This `var id  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();`  is getting Sheet Id not the spreadsheet id.

Comment: The Spreadsheet Id of the Active Spreadsheet is `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();`  or you can look at the url in the browser it's d/thisstring/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Spreadsheet Id:**

function getSpreadsheetId(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
}

Comment: I didn't realize I was pulling up the Sheet ID instead of the Spreadsheet ID, no wonder it didn't work... But this! YOU ARE A GENIUS! THANK YOU SO MUCH!